# DAX - Get list from a filtered SUMMARIZE formula

Tags: powerbi, dax

So, I have the following tables in my Power BI :

```
Sales : Date | ID_Client | ID_Product | Amount
Client : ID_Client | Name_Client
```

I would like to get the number of unique BIG clients in any given month. I therefore use the following formula (which I then put in a column in a table with months in rows):

```
# BIG Clients =
VAR threshold = 10000
RETURN
     (
        CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT( Sales[ID_Client] ),
            FILTER(
                SUMMARIZE(
                    Sales,
                    Sales[ID_Client],
                    "Sales", SUM( Sales[Amount] )
                ),
                [Sales] >= threshold
            )
        )
    )
```

**QUESTION IS** : how can I get the list of those BIG clients for any given month? Let's say I click on the November number of big clients in my table, could another table nearby display the list of those clients ?

Thanks in advance for your kind help, I've been trying for a while :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have a table of clients with the `Name` column with a one to many relationship with the Sales table and that you do not have duplicate client names. Then you may create a `[BIG Sales]` measure to be used in a table or matrix visual with client names on the rows.

since `[BIG Sales]` evaluates to `BLANK()` for clients with less that `threshold` sales, they are automatically filtered out from the visual

```
BIG Sales =
VAR threshold = 10000
VAR BigCustomers =
    FILTER(
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            VALUES( Clients[Name] ),
            "Sales", SUM( Sales[Amount] )
        ),
        [Sales] >= threshold
    )
RETURN
    SUMX(
        BigCustomers,
        [Sales]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table or matrix visual with the client on the rows and use your measure in the values field. This will show `1` for all big clients and return blank for the rest (which should hide them). If you don't want to show the measure, you can set the value is 1 in the filter pane and remove the measure from the values field.

[image: Big Client filter]

A more direct option is to use a simple `SalesAmount = SUM ( Sales[Amount] )` measure in the values field and filter like this

[image: SalesAmount filter]

Comment: When I create a table with the ID_Client on rows I get a list of ALL the ID_Clients in my base and nothing changes when I select - for example - the November number of BIG clients. This is because by BIG_Client formula above is filtering everything by itself but I haven't found how I can access the list of the clients returned by the formula  rather than the distinct could of how much clients there is (which is what the formula is doing)

Comment: You can't access it directly because a measure has to return a single value rather than a table but you can use it as a filter. I've edited my answer for a bit more clarity.